# How Does This Bookmarklet Bypass The Site's Filter Of Prompts?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, inject

So, my problem is that I am trying to find out how this bookmarklet bypasses the website's blocking of the code `prompt('')`; but I can't find it so I need help figuring out how this works.
Here's the code for the bookmarklet

```
(() => {
  const c = async() => {
    var e = document.createElement("iframe"),
      e = (document.body.append(e), window.prompt = e.contentWindow.prompt.bind(window), e.remove(), Object.values(function e(t = document.querySelector("body>div")) {
        return Object.values(t)[1]?.children?.[0]?._owner.stateNode ? t : e(t.querySelector(":scope>div"))
      }())[1].children[0]._owner.stateNode)["props"];
    e.client.blook = prompt("Blook Name: (Case Sensitive)"), e.liveGameController.setVal({
      path: `c/${e.client.name}/b`,
      val: e.client.blook
    })
  };
  let l = new Image;
  l.src = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/05Konz/Blooket-Cheats/main/autoupdate/timestamps/global/changeBlookIngame.png?"
  Date.now(), l.crossOrigin = "Anonymous", l.onload = function() {
    var e = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
    e.drawImage(l, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    let t = e.getImageData(0, 0, this.width, this.height)["data"],
      o = "",
      n;
    for (let e = 0; e < t.length; e = 4) {
      var a = String.fromCharCode(256 * t[e 1] t[e 2]);
      if (o = a, "/" == a && "*" == n) break;
      n = a
    }
    var e = document.querySelector("iframe"),
      [, r, i] = o.match(/LastUpdated: (. ?); ErrorMessage: "(. ?)"/);
    (parseInt(r) <= 1693429947381 || e.contentWindow.confirm(i)) && c()
  }, l.onerror = l.onabort = () => (l.src = null, c())
})();
```

that is all my problem is.

I tried finding an extracting the part that allows it to work but I couldn't so, I tried to google it and seach it up on this website but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates an iframe with:

```
var e = document.createElement("iframe")
```

then copies the iframe's `prompt()` function to the current window:

```
window.prompt = e.contentWindow.prompt.bind(window)
```

This reverts `prompt()` to the default function.

Comment: How does it run `prompt()` from the iframe tho? Also Could I do it with this bookmarklet? `javascript: var x = document.createElement('script');x.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/SnowLord7/devconsole@master/main.js';document.head.appendChild(x);`

Comment: It's not running it from the iframe. It's basically just copying the code, since `window.prompt` is normally a reference to the same native function in all windows/frames.

Comment: I think that bookmarklet should work. What happens when you try it?

Comment: Could you make a bookmarklet that uses what you said and then alerts the output?

Comment: Also, That Bookmarklet Is A recreation of the inspect element but I can't get it to work on some websites.

Comment: I haven't read the whole bookmarklet, it's lots of code with no meaningful variable names. I just read the first couple of lines to answer your question.

Comment: It's okay but I am trying to do it myself or someone else can answer my question

Comment: I made a bookmarklet that does the thing I was trying to get. `javascript:(function(){var n = document.getElementById("AlertPromptConfirmFixer");if(n){n.remove();}n = document.createElement("iframe");n.id = "AlertPromptConfirmFixer";n.style.display = "none";document.body.appendChild(n);window.alert = n.contentWindow.alert;window.prompt = n.contentWindow.prompt;window.confirm = n.contentWindow.confirm;})();`